# How to include comments from Nmap script in the output file

Tags: linux, bash, nmap

There might be a better way to do this, but what I have is an input file called "list.txt" of IP addresses for my Nmap scan like so:

```
192.168.1.1   #Router
192.168.1.120 #PC
192.168.1.52  #Phone
```

Then I scan with Nmap using and output to a file using:

```
nmap -iL list.txt >> output.txt
```

Additionally I have used sed to make the "output.txt" look like this:

```
Host: 192.168.1.1       Status: Up
Host: 192.168.1.120     Status: Down
Host: 192.168.1.52      Status: Up
```

I would like to include the comments from the input "list.txt" file, but cannot find a way this can be done. The ideal "output.txt" would look like this:

```
Host: 192.168.1.1       Status: Up    #Router
Host: 192.168.1.120     Status: Down  #PC
Host: 192.168.1.52      Status: Up    #Phone
```

Is there a way to include the comments in the "list.txt" to be in the "output.txt"?

Comment: You'll probably need to read the file line by line in your script, and call `nmap` separately for each IP. Then you can write the comment to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to run awk with the original file and the new output.txt file:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { ip[$1]=$2;next } { printf "%s\t%s\n",$0,ip[$2] }' list.txt output.txt > finaloutput.txt
```

Process the first (NR==FNR) and create an array called IP with the IP address (first space delimited field) as the key and the comment the value. Then when processing the second file (output.txt), print the line, plus the comment for the IP taken from the ip array.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file in a shell loop so you can get the comment and write it to the output file.

```
while read -r ip comment; do
    result=$(nmap "$ip")
    printf '%36s  %s\n', "$result" "$comment"
done < list.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea using `join`:

```
$ join -1 1 -2 2 -o2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,1.2 list.txt output.txt
Host: 192.168.1.1 Status: Up #Router
Host: 192.168.1.120 Status: Down #PC
Host: 192.168.1.52 Status: Up #Phone
```

To reformat into a 'pretty' `-t`able:

```
$ join -1 1 -2 2 -o2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,1.2 list.txt output.txt | column -t
Host:  192.168.1.1    Status:  Up    #Router
Host:  192.168.1.120  Status:  Down  #PC
Host:  192.168.1.52   Status:  Up    #Phone
```

**NOTE:** this solution assumes both files are already sorted by IP; otherwise the files need to be pre-sorted, eg:

```
join -1 1 -2 2 -o2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,1.2 <(sort list.txt) <(sort -k2,2 output.txt) [ | column -t ]
```